# Don't understand how to print the search path of a skip list

Tags: java

I am busy with an assignment where I am expected to print out(display) all the nodes that the skip list visited when searchin for a specific element.

The code that follows is my search algorithm. I am not sure where to put the output lines to show the search path of each node.

```
public SkipListNode<T> search(T key) {

    SkipListNode<T> prev, curr;
    int currlevel;

    for (currlevel = maxLevel; currlevel >= 0 && root[currlevel] == null; currlevel--)
        ;

    if (root[0] == null)
        return null;
    prev = curr = root[currlevel];
    while (true) {
        if (key.equals(curr.key)) {
            return curr;
        } else if (key.compareTo(curr.key) < 0) {
            if (currlevel < 1)
                return null;
            else if (curr == root[currlevel])
                curr = root[--currlevel];
            else {
                curr = prev.next[--currlevel];
            }
        } else if (key.compareTo(curr.key) > 0) {
            prev = curr;
            if (curr.next[currlevel] != null)
                curr = curr.next[currlevel];
            else {
                for (currlevel--; currlevel >= 0 && root[currlevel] == null; currlevel--)
                    ;
                if (currlevel >= 0)
                    curr = curr.next[currlevel];
                else
                    return null;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Whenever you re-assign curr.

Comment: Ack! You have a **semi-colon** DIRECTLY after the closing parenthesis of your for loop: `for (currlevel = maxLevel; currlevel >= 0 && root[currlevel] == null; currlevel--);`. This means the `if` statement immediately following DOES NOT "belong" to the for loop. The for loop has an empty body and won't actually do anything. Get rid of that semi-colon! This type of bug is super hard to spot as it does not produce a compile-time error or warning.

Comment: @Idle_Mind This was actually done purposfully and was also done in our textbook for my course. This forloop is used to check for empty levels of the skip list. The for loop is going to keep looping until the level is not null. Thus means there is a level with actual nodes in it. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Ew...using a for loop like that is confusing. Shame on that book. I'd change the declaration of "currlevel" to `int currlevel = maxLevel;` and then change the for loop to a while: `while (currlevel >= 0 && root[currlevel] == null) { currlevel--; }`.

Comment: To answer your question, though, immediately after the `while (true) {` line, just output the node that `curr` points to?...